# Sign-up/Login/Password reset - Is this a good and secure solution?

Tags: authentication, passwords

I'm working with a dev agency for a web-based platform. Here is how they are planning to handle sign-ups on the platform as well as log-in and password reset.

Is it a good, robust and secure solution?

**Registration**:
We use library ‘crypto’ and PBKDF2. Parameters for this function: password, salt, iteration number, hash length and HMAC algorithm (sha512). We save this hash in the database.

**Authorization**:
We use Bearer Token with library `jsonwebtoken` for validation.

**Recovery**:
We send a URL with a recovery token that expires after 60 minutes.

Comment: Can I assume that the spec is a copy/paste from the developers and you are asking us if their design makes sense?

Comment: What you describe is *so* high level, and *so* lacking in details, that we can't possible comment meaningfully on any part of it. The details *matter* in building a secure system, the details are what makes a system secure or insecure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably good enough as a bare minimum, but there are a lot of improvements that could be made, and it's under-specified. A few specific points to consider:

- PBKDF2 is an older algorithm, and its lack of memory hardness means it's easy to parallelize, which helps with cracking attempts. I'd recommend using something newer (in descending order, argon2, scrypt, bcrypt).
- You don't specify the length or source of the salt. It should be at least 64 bits (more than 128 probably doesn't add much), cryptographically random, and unique for every user.
- You don't specify the the iteration count / work factor. It should be as high as your server can tolerate without posing a denial-of-service risk (including, without users being able to notice a slowdown at busy times).
- You don't describe how the password verifier (hash) is stored. Some libraries return a formatted string containing the algorithm, salt, work factor, and hash; that's fine. If yours doesn't, you need to store every one of those values. (Don't hard-code the work factor or algorithm; you may want to update them in the future, in which case you need to know what was used for each existing entry).
- You don't mention anything about password quality. While traditional "complexity" rules are somewhere between minimally useful and actively harmful, length is important (eight characters is the minimum, requiring more is reasonably for very sensitive sites) and you should check the candidate password against a list of known breached passwords ("haveibeenpwned" maintains such a "pwned passwords" list, and code for checking it)
- You should have an option for multi-factor authentication, especially if you're storing any kind of sensitive data.
- What algorithm are you using to sign the JWTs? Make sure it's the only one accepted, too.
- Where are you storing the JWT signing key? Ideally it should be in some key management service, not just hanging out in a persistent file or similar. An attacker who gets ahold of it can forge arbitrary JWTs.
- How long are your JWTs good for? Note that there's no good way to revoke or invalidate a JWT, so they typically remain usable until expiration. For this reason, many sites use very short expirations (single-digit minutes) and combine the JWT with a refresh token (an opaque, cryptographically-random string with at least 128 bits of entropy, which is generated uniquely for each user, stored in hashed form in the DB and also in the client in local storage, and can be exchanged for a new JWT).
- What is the source of the recovery URL? Assuming it contains a random secret (as it should), what random generator does it come from and how much entropy does it have (not the same as how long it is; a 32-character hex string has at most 16 bytes of entropy)? As with the refresh tokens, cryptographically random strings of at least 128 bits (16 bytes) are recommended, and the token should be stored in the DB in hashed form.
- A one-hour expiration is fine for the password reset link, but consider also making it single-use.
- Logging is important, and you generally want to log both positive security outcomes (user authenticated, password reset, etc.) and negative ones (bad refresh token received, user tried to access unauthorized resource, etc.). However, make sure to not log any actual secrets (passwords, tokens, etc.).
- You need some anti-brute-forcing protection on login (*especially* if you don't support multi-factor authentication). Try to ensure that it can't be used to prevent legitimate users from logging in. I prefer either a CAPTCHA after some number of failed login attempts, or an email sent directly to the attacked user that can be used to log in directly.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty hard to tell whether it is safe by these three points as it also depends on how you configure these with other parts of your app. But if possible, I would suggest 2FA for authentication. Apart from this, I would suggest a few things you should be aware of:

1. Make sure you follow the JWT security practice (e.g. none algorithm shouldn't be allowed, always check issuer etc.). You can find out more from this article: https://curity.io/resources/learn/jwt-best-practices/
2. Make sure recovery function works and secured (You may follow my post about how to test a password reset function: https://medium.com/techiepedia/5-ways-to-test-password-reset-function-78edf77cac5a)